# subprocess.check_output failing with error 127

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm attempting to call an outside program from my python application, but it shows no output and fails with error 127.  Executing the command from the command line works fine.  (and I am in the correct working directory)

```
def buildContris (self, startUrl, reportArray):
    urls = []

    for row in reportArray:
        try:
            url = subprocess.check_output(["casperjs", "casper.js", startUrl, row[0]], shell=True)
            print (url)
            urls.append(url)
            break
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print ("Error: " + str(e.returncode) + " Output:" + e.output.decode())          

    return urls
```

Each loop outputs the following error: (I've also checked e.cmd.  It's correct, but long, so I omitted it in this example)

```
Error: 127 Output:
```

**SOLUTION:**

The following code works

```
app = subprocess.Popen(["./casperjs/bin/casperjs", "casper.js", startUrl, row[0]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env = {"PATH" : "/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin"}, universal_newlines=True)
app.wait()
out, errs = app.communicate()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the full path to casperjs in your subprocess.check_output() call.

Edit: Answeing your 2nd question. My apologies for the formatting as I'm on iPad.
I think you should try Popen instead of check_output so that you can specify environment variables:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/casperjs", "casper.js", startUrl, row[0]], env={"PATH": "/path/to/phantomjs"})
url, err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: That gets me actual output, however, it now fails saying that it cannot find phantomjs.  I assume that's because it's not finding my PATH.  Is there a way to specify that?

Comment: I appended my answer to include PATH environment variable. What OS are you running this on?

Comment: OSX.  I'll give Popen a look and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: Got it.  The following code worked.  I'll also add it to the initial question for formatting's sake.  Thanks!

Comment: app = subprocess.Popen(["./casperjs/bin/casperjs", "casper.js", startUrl, row[0]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env = {"PATH" : "/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin"}, universal_newlines=True)
                app.wait()
                out, errs = app.communicate()

Comment: Get full paths of programs using `which {program name}`.

Answer (score 1):

`shell=True` changes the interpretation of the first argument (`args`) in `check_output()` call, [from the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> On Unix with shell=True, ... If args is a
>   sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
>   *additional items* will be treated as additional arguments to *the shell
>   itself*. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
> ```

Exit status `127` might mean that the shell haven't found `casperjs` program or `casperjs` itself exited with that code.

To fix the code: drop `shell=True` and specify the full path to the `casperjs` program e.g.:

```
url = check_output(["./casperjs", "casper.js", startUrl, row[0]])
```

Comment: I see.  So I removed shell=True and passed the full path of casperjs, but I got an error saying that it can't find phantomjs.

    "Error: 1 Output:Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?"

I also re-added shell=True but formatted the command as follows:

    "url = subprocess.check_output(["./casperjs/bin/casperjs casper.js " + startUrl + " " + row[0]], shell=True)"

And got the same error except error 127 instead of error 1 

    "Error: 127 Output:Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?"

Edit: Formatting

Comment: I guess the error is coming from check_output()'s inability to read my PATH.  Is there a way to specify a PATH for it to use?

Comment: @Jeff: `print(os.environ)` and compare it with `check_call("/usr/bin/env")` I suspect they are very similar i.e., your problem is not that subprocess sees different `$PATH` than the Python script. Though you can use `env` parameter to set a custom environment for the subprocess. `check_output()` passes all arguments to `Popen()` that it uses internally.

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing this kinda nonsense on macOS: **don't use aliases**. Lost half a day with that. So, change:

```
subprocess.check_output(
    "scribus-ng -g -ns -py {0} {1}".format(script_path, id),
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True)
```

to

```
subprocess.check_output(
    "/Applications/Scribus.app/Contents/MacOS/Scribus -g -ns -py {0} {1}".format(script_path, id),
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add explicitly the path in this way.
If the file to call is in the same path (change `__file__` if not):

```
cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
a  = subprocess.check_output(["./casper.js", startUrl, row[0]],cwd=cwd,shell=True)
```