# Running a Python script in R Script is giving error

Tags: python, r, shiny, install.packages

I want to run a Python script in RShiny. I'm doing this by source() function but it is giving me error. I'm very new to R. Do anyone know how can I run task1 in Server.R? My OS is Windows.

server.R:

```
library(shiny) #library
library(shinydashboard) #library
library(devtools)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$actionID,{
    source("task1.py")
  })
})
```

task1.py:

```
from PIL import Image
print("Mayday! Mayday!")
```

Error that I'm getting is:

```
Warning: Error in source: task1.py:6:6: unexpected input
5: 
6: from PIL
        ^
  73: source
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work because `source()` implies that you want the file to be interpreted by R, not by Python.

You can use `system()` for any command you want to send to the OS, including running Python against a `.py`.

Example:

```
system("C:\\Python27\\python.exe my_script.py")
```

You can specify if R should wait and if any output should be captured, etc.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Warning: running command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\python.exe tss.py' had status 127

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker  That's a different problem, but it sounds like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649549/subprocess-check-output-failing-with-error-127  If you need more help please open a new question for it and link me.